# Rails ActiveRecord after_initialize and overriden accessor method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my code example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :account

  after_initialize :setup_account

  def setup_account
    self.account = Account.new
  end

  def email=(email)
    self.account.email = email
    super(email)
  end

end
```

Now, the following call is failing:

```
User.new(email: 'hello@example.com')
```

Because this is executing the email= method before the setup_account method, where the account variable would be set.

How would you change this code to work as expected? I know the copying of email is a bad thing to do, but it could have been something else instead of a simple copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following. It doesn't use any callbacks, but lazily creates an account or returns an existing one.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, autosave: true

  # ...

  def user_account
    self.account ||= Account.new
  end

  def email=(email)
    user_account.email = email
    super
  end
end
```

You also need to specify that you want to autosave the `account` association when you save the user object. Otherwise you would have to do it manually when updating an user record.